# Selecting a sequence of elements from the IList

Tags: c#, wcf, list

I have a IList. where the object PersonDetails consists of the persons name, address and phone number. The list consists of more than 1000 person details. I would like to display 50 PersonDetails per page. Is there a way to select only 50 elements from the list, and return them.
For example.

```
myList.select(1,50)
myList.select(51, 100)
```

I am able to select only first 50 by using. `myList.Take(50);`
The entire list is at the wcf service, and i would like to get only fifty elements at a time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will select second 50 elements (by skipping first 50):

```
var elements = myList
    .Skip(50)
    .Take(50)
    .ToList();
```

[`Skip` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) bypasses a specified number of elements in a sequence and then returns the remaining elements.